# Как заменять элементы при дубликатах, когда нету уникальных столбцов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Суть проблемы: мне нужно заносить в базу данных данные и в случае, если они уже там есть, то заменять их. Но дело в том, что уникальных столбцов там нету, чтобы сделать `ON CONFLICT(column) DO UPDATE` ...

Как можно сверять по нескольким колонкам или же полностью.

P.S.  При попытке `ON CONFLICT(column1, column2, column3)` вылазит следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

Comment: Ошибка говорит вам, что нету `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` на эти столбцы.  Добавьте это ограничение, и заработает.

Comment: дело в том, что они не уникальные и не должны таковыми быть

Comment: То есть, у вас есть столбцы, которые «как бы уникальные», и когда по ним есть совпадение, нужно в других столбцах поменять данные, так?

Comment: @VincentVega На сколько я понял, вам предлагают создать один UNIQUE CONSTRAINT на несколько столбцов сразу.

Comment: у меня нету уникальных столбцов, но я думаю можно как-то считать уникальными по нескольким столбцам.

Comment: Определите, пожалуйста, конкретные условия и добавьте их в вопрос.  Пока что плохо понятно, как это должно работать.

Comment: @VincentVega Ну да, например так:
`ALTER TABLE someTable
ADD UNIQUE (col1, col2)`

Comment: спасибо за идею, щас попробую

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо большое